# Remove duplicate address values where length of second column is less than the length of the greatest matching address

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm not sure if I worded the title properly so I apologize.  I feel this is best explained by showing my data.

```
Address 1                               Address 2            City          State      AddressInfo#
--------------------------------        ------------------   ------------  -----      --------------
1 Main St #100 Burbville, CA, 99999     1 Main St #100       Burbville     CA         1001
1 Main St #100 Burbville, CA, 99999     1 Main St            Burbville     CA         1001
1 Main St #100 Burbville, CA, 99999     1 Main st            Burbville     CA         1001
...
4 Old Ave Ste 401 Southtown, OH, 44444  4 Old Ave Ste 401    Southtown     OH         1004
4 Old Ave Ste 401 Southtown, OH, 44444  4 Old Ave Ste 401    Southtown     OH         1004
...
8 New Blvd #800 NewCity, MT, 88888      8 New Blvd #800      NewCity       MT         1008
8 New Blvd #800 NewCity, MT, 88888      8 New Blvd           NewCity       MT         1008
8 New Blvd #800 NewCity, MT, 88888      8 New Blvd           NewCity       MT         1008
```

I would like to find a way to remove all records where Address 2 is missing the full street address or simply contains an exact duplicate like AddressInfo# 1004.

Expected Output:

```
Address 1                               Address 2            City          State      AddressInfo#
--------------------------------        ------------------   ------------  -----      --------------
1 Main St #100 Burbville, CA, 99999     1 Main St #100       Burbville     CA         1001
...
4 Old Ave Ste 401 Southtown, OH, 44444  4 Old Ave Ste 401    Southtown     OH         1004
...
8 New Blvd #800 NewCity, MT, 88888      8 New Blvd #800      NewCity       MT         1008
```

Comment: Is there a unique identifier column, or are those two rows truly exact duplicates?

Comment: Truly duplicates.  Originally the AddressInfo# was the unique identifier but I exported these addresses to a CASS tool to get the addresses scrubbed and split into separate columns.  Unfortunately the tool has created these duplicates so I need to remove them.

Comment: But 1004 is associated with two.  Show the expected output.

Comment: @Blam Sorry about that.  I've updated the table data and the expected output.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rebuild your data into a new table using

```
select 
address_1,max(address_2) as address_2, addressinfo
from 
table1 
group by address_1,addressinfo
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3d22c/2

**Edit 1:** 
To select `city` and `state` as well you need to include it as a `group by` expression:

```
select 
address_1,max(address_2) as address_2, addressinfo,
city, state
from 
table1 
group by address_1,addressinfo, city, state
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4527c/1

**Edit 2:** 
The `max` function does deliver the longest value here as needed. This works if the shorter values are true starts of the longer values.

Here is an example of this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3fba8/1

Comment: This works until I add the city and state to the group by clause.  How can I select all columns and remove the duplicates?

Comment: It should work if you add city and state to your group by. What error do you get?

Comment: Look at my answer. The second fiddle does not deliver duplicates. So you did something different in this SQL or the data differs from what you posted.

Comment: max(address_2) is not going to give you the longest

Comment: @Blam Can you elaborate?  It appears to work if I'm looking at the data correctly.

Comment: @Blam: Max does delivers the longest if the data is like the OP posted. The shorter ones are exact starts of the longer ones. If there are differences like '1 Main St #100' and '1 Mein St' you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Some form of:

```
UPDATE A
   SET Address2 = CASE WHEN Address1 = Address2 THEN NULL ELSE 
                    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',',Address2,CHARINDEX(',',Address2)) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE Address2 END
                  END

FROM Address AS A
```

Comment: This just turns everything into a NULL.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        Address1
    ,   Address2
    ,   [AddressInfo#]
    ,   City
    ,   State
    -- + any other fields
FROM dbo.Table1 AS t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM dbo.Table1 AS x
        WHERE x.Address1 = t.Address1
            -- + any other criteria for "uniqueness"
            AND LEFT( x.Address2, LEN( t.Address2 ) ) = t.Address2
            AND LEN( x.Address2 ) > LEN( t.Address2 )
    );
```

This query will first get all the rows where there is not another row with the same Address1 and an Address2 matching the current value up to the length of the field, but at least one character longer.  The DISTINCT is then applied to eliminate exact duplicates.  (This assumes no NULL values.)

A similar query could use the LIKE operator, but this would need to account for special characters in the data, such as "%", "_", or brackets.

Answer (score 0):

This may have syntax errors but this is a valid approach

```
with cte as 
(
   select address1, address2, city, state, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by AddressInfo# order by len(address2) desc) as 'alen'
)
select * from cte  
 where alen = 1
```

Comment: There are difinitely some syntax errors.  Just by itself I get errors stating it is unable to find the column names.  If I add a from clause to the subquery I then get an incorrect syntax in your Where clause and I'm unsure what your where clause is trying to accomplish.

Comment: where alen = 1 is the row with the longest len(address2).  This is a valid approach.